# Chinese International student wanting to enter US on F-1 Visa

Tags: china, study, student-visas

My girlfriend wants to enter the US as a Chinese citizen on a F1 visa, back to university.  What are the best ways to do this?  It seems like she will need to quarantine somewhere for 14 days, what are the easiest/most cost-effective choices for countries?  She ideally do not want to apply for a travel Visa.  Thank you!

Comment: Does she already have f1 visa?

Comment: Yes she does @FranckDernoncourt

Comment: This page is relatively current: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Chinese_citizens

Comment: Isn't this [expatriates.se] ?

Comment: This is (a year old and refers to very different covid requirements than currently apply but) about the travel part of a long-term visa, contains nothing F1-specific that wouldn't also apply to a B visitory, and is IMO suitable for this site.

Answer (score 1):

> enter the US as a Chinese citizen on a F1 visa

That depends on where she is currently located. https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php -> USA:

> students with an F-1 or M-1 visa and their F-2 and M-2 dependents [are allowed] if they arrive from or have been in Ireland (Rep.), United Kingdom or Schengen Member States in the past 14 days.

I'm confused what "arrive from country X" means. According to an English dictionary, this means that it doesn't matter how much time one spent in country C. But this contradicts common sense. As a result, I don't know whether she can fly China -> Schengen/UK/IE -> US without staying in Schengen/UK/IE for over 14 days. My guess is no but worth calling some Chinese embassy in the US to confirm, because the information on IATA is ambiguous.

Comment: The [exception](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/News/visas-news/national-interest-exceptions-from-certain-travelers-from-the-schengen-area-uk-and-ireland.html) for students from Europe applies to the Proclamations 9993 and 9996 (the entry bans for people who have been present in the Schengen Area, the UK, and Ireland in the last 14 days). I don't think it would negate Proclamation 9984 (the entry bans for people who have been present in Mainland China in the last 14 days).

Comment: @user102008 thanks, agreed, upon reading iata I now understand what they meant. Confusingly written.